# How do you transform from one form of Hamiltonian to another?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

Suppose we are given a Hamiltonian $$H=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{q^2}+p^2q^4\right)$$ where $q,p$ constitute a canonical pair of degrees of freedom.

Now we are asked to go to a Hamiltonian of the form of a harmonic oscillator, by some canonical transformation $(q,p)\rightarrow(Q,P)$.
I think we can write the new Hamiltonian as follows: $$H'=\frac{P^2}{2}+\frac{Q^2}{2}.$$

The question is to find the form of $Q$ and $P$. But I am clueless on how to proceed. Does generating function has anything to do here? We know $$H-H'=\frac{\partial F}{\partial t},$$ can we somehow use this relation to get $F$?

Any hints will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing $H$ and $H'$, the transformations
$$P=\pm pq^2,\quad\quad Q=\pm {1\over q}$$
would do the job. I suggest you to check that it is indeed a canonical transformation (with the appropriate signs) by computing the Poisson brackets $\{Q,Q\}$, $\{P,P\}$, and $\{Q,P\}$.